# How to parse custom PROXY protocol v2 header for custom routing in HAProxy configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, haproxy, aws-vpc, proxy-protocol

How can one parse the PROXY protocol version 2 header and use the parsed values to select a backend?

Specifically, I am making a connection from one AWS account to another using a VPC PrivateLink endpoint with PROXY v2 enabled. This includes the endpoint ID according to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#proxy-protocol).

> The Proxy Protocol header also includes the ID of the endpoint. This information is encoded using a custom Type-Length-Value (TLV) vector as follows.

My goal is to connect from a resource A in account 1 to a resource B in account 2. The plan is resource A -> PrivateLink -> NLB (with PROXY v2 enabled) -> HAProxy -> resource B.

I need to detect the VPC PrivateLink endpoint ID in the HAProxy frontend to select the correct backend. How can this be done? I'm not clear on how to call a custom parser in the HAProxy configuration, or if this is even possible? Is it? If so, how can this be done?

Reason I can't just use source IP: It is possible for private IP spaces to overlap in my architecture. There will be several accounts acting as account 1 in the example above, so I have to do destination routing based on the endpoint ID rather than the source IP exposed by the PROXY usage.

### Examples

#### Not good

This is our current scenario. In it, two inbound connections from different VPC's having the same private IP address space cannot be distinguished.

```
frontend salt_4506_acctA_front
        bind 10.0.1.32:4506 accept-proxy
        mode tcp
        default_backend salt_4506_acctA_back

backend salt_4506_acctA_back
        balance roundrobin
        mode tcp
        server salt-master-ecs 192.168.0.88:32768
```

If we need to route connections for acctB's VPC using the same IP, there would be no way to distinguish.

#### Ideal

An ideal solution would be to modify this to something like the following (though I recognize this is won't work; it is just pseudo-configuration).

```
frontend salt_4506_acctA_front
        bind *:4506 accept-proxy if endpointID == vpce-xxxxxxx1
        mode tcp
        default_backend salt_4506_acctA_back

backend salt_4506_acctA_back
        balance roundrobin
        mode tcp
        server salt-master-ecs 192.168.0.88:32768
```

---

Any other options in place of HAProxy for destination routing based on the endpoint ID are also acceptable, but HAProxy seemed like the obvious candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like AWS use the "2.2.7. Reserved type ranges" as described in https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt therefore you will need to parse this part by your own.

This could be possible in lua, maybe I'm not an expert in lua, yet ;-)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding where lua comes into the picture. I see several ways to parse the header contents, but not how to incorporate this into the HAProxy configuration.

Comment: Well the proxy protocol is before any http header so you will need to take a look if it's possible to intercept this step.

Comment: I was referring to the PROXY header not the HTTP header. It seems HAProxy should be able to extract the TLV's and provide matching in ACL's.

Comment: Well afaik isn't there a fetch method for that. Contribution is welcome.

Comment: I would certainly consider contribution once I have a full account of what is possible and fully understand what shape that contribution would take, but I still feel like I may be overlooking the detail required. Basically I'd like to see the ability to use `acl vpce tlv(0xEA) -m end v-1234`.

Comment: I have requested on the mailing list of haproxy if this is possible. https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg28713.html